# Change image when click imagebutton item custom listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-imagebutton

I have a custom listview, each item have a imagebutton, i want to change image of each imagebutton immediately when I click. Each item in custom listview is a object named baiHat{}. 
I use BaiHatAdapter like this, but it not chane immediately, i must scroll listview to see change.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row=inflater.inflate(this.resource, null);
    TextView txtMs = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ms);
    TextView txtBh = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.bh);
    TextView txtCs = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cs);
    TextView txtLr = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lr);
    ImageButton imglike = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    final BaiHat baiHat = this.objects.get(position);
    txtMs.setText(baiHat.getTxtms());
    txtBh.setText(baiHat.getTenBh());
    txtCs.setText(baiHat.getTxtcs());
    txtLr.setText(baiHat.getTxtLr());
    imglike.setImageResource(baiHat.getImg());
   imglike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           xulythich(baiHat);
        }
    });
    return row;
}

private void xulythich(BaiHat baiHat) {
    if(baiHat.getThich()){
     baiHat.setThich(false);
     baiHat.setImg(R.drawable.addfav);

            }else{
        baiHat.setThich(true);
       baiHat.setImg(R.drawable.added);
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a *selector* file and assigning it as src would work. But as a better approach you can try to change it to togglebutton, since imageview is not meant to be clickable and give it the background of selector source.
It will just look like any imageview but with the capability of being clickable and changing its background from the selector file.